# How to handle AggregateException from tasks in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

I get an AggregateException from the below function which has a task that calls a database function GetStatementsFromDB(). The stack trace shows the inner exception which is SqlException (Timeout expired). How can I rethrow the exception gracefully from this function and continue with the calling function? Currently, it does not continue the execution in the calling function.

Thanks for any advice!

```
Public Function GetStatements() As String

        Dim task1 As Task(Of String) = Task(Of String).Factory.StartNew(Function()
                                                                            Return GetStatementsFromDB()
                                                                        End Function)
        mStatements = task1.Result
        Return mStatements

End Function
```

Comment: Your code as is not at all useful. No point in starting new Task and immediately waiting for it. You don't need a `Task` at all. Simply call `GetStatementsFromDB` synchronously.

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will change it to make it asynchronous.

Comment: If I use ContinueWith on the task, will that make it asynchronous? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but be sure you're not waiting for it either. `Await` could be another option.

Comment: I can't use async and await pattern as the project is using 4.0 Framework. What options do I have to make the database call ayschronous? Thank you!

Comment: If you're using VS2012, you can still use async/await using [Async pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) while targeting to .Net framework 4.0 itself. Otherwise just use `ContinueWith`. There are lots of tutorials how to use both, In case you're struck, feel free to ask a new question here.